# Django Jquery plugin to play audio files

Tags: django, stream

I am developing new website in Django 1.3 where after a customer has purchased , he can stream the audio files within the website.

I  looked online and found 
http://pyjax.net/blog/1/2007/06/27/django-flash-audioplayer/
or using the following jquery plugins mentioned in
http://jquery.malsup.com/media/video.html

The audio files are large and I want to go for a secure way to stream these audio files. Please suggest the best way to handle this using Django with Apache2.2